# Define Perl while() = each {} loop with inline hash

Tags: perl

I am trying to define an inline hash in a while each loop, my program is not throwing any errors but also doesn't execute the print statement. Is it possible to define an inline hash like below:

```
while (my (key, value) = each %{ (apple  => "red", orange => "orange", grape  => "purple")}) { 
    print "something";
}
```

or alternatively I can't while each loop to work if I directly call a sub in the each statement that returns a hash like the following:

```
sub returnsHash {
    my %fruits = (
        apple  => "red",
        orange => "orange",
        grape  => "purple",
    );
    return %fruits;
}

while (my (key, value) = each %{ returnsHash() }) { 
    print "something";
}
```

Comment: what is output of `returnsHash` ?

Comment: It can be anything that returns an hash, edited my question

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!! It would have identified the problem you are asking about.

Comment: Re "*It can be anything that returns an hash, edited my question*", The `returnHash` in your question doesn't return a hash; it returns 6 strings. In fact, it's impossible to return a hash; sub can only return scalars. It is possible for a sub to return a reference to a hash, but that's not what you have or said.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A list/comma operator in scalar context evaluates to the result of the last item evaluated in scalar context. That means

```
each %{ apple => "red", orange => "orange", grape  => "purple" }
```

is equivalent to

```
each %{ "purple" }
```

This is what both of your snippets are doing, but it's undesired, and it's a strict violation. (*Always* use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!!)

You are using a hash dereference (`%{ ... }`), but you have no hash, much less a reference to a hash that you can dereference. To build a hash and return a reference to the hash, use `{ ... }`.

```
each %{ { apple  => "red", orange => "orange", grape  => "purple" } }
```

While that solves a problem, but just reveals another problem: You get an endless loop.

The iterator used by `each`, `keys` and `values` is associated with the hash, not the operator. Since you are creating a new hash each time through the loop, you are creating a new iterator each time through the loop, so you will always get the first element of the newly created hash, and your loop will never end.

Since you have no need to look up items by key, I don't see why you're using a hash at all. You could use the following instead:

```
for (
   [ apple  => "red"    ],
   [ orange => "orange" ],
   [ grape  => "purple" ],
) {
   my ($key, $val) = @$_;
   ...
}
```

The following is how you'd write the above if you got the list from a sub.

```
use List::Util qw( pairs );

for (pairs(f())) {
   my ($key, $val) = @$_;
   ...
}
```

Both of those create many arrays, though. Since there's no issue with being destructive, I would use the following which avoids the issue:

```
{
   my @kvs = f();
   while ( my ($key, $val) = splice(@kvs, 0, 2) ) {
      ...
   }
}
```

You could also use the following, but I think many would be confused by it:

```
for (
   my @kvs = f();
   my ($key, $val) = splice(@kvs, 0, 2);
) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That can't be done since [each](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) only works as intended with an actual *variable*, a hash or an array. See the synopsis in docs.  Same goes for [keys](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) and [values](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html).

It is the same with the second attempt, where the function is also called anew in every iteration.

Note that a sensible thing to try would be `%{ {...} }` (and not `%{ (...) }`) since the thing inside `%{}` must be a hash reference. This applies to both attempts as the function returns a hash, whereby you get back a list of scalars. (This still wouldn't help, per the first statement.)

---

I am not sure what the need is for this, as a hash can be defined before the loop. Also, I'd like to suggest to carefully look at `each` before using it since it comes with complexities.

I take it that you want to iterate over key-value pairs of a dynamically created list of such pairs. Here is a way to do that using a custom iterator (which wraps the hash iterator used by `each`)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $hit = get_each_it(a => 1, b => 2, c => 3);

while (my ($k, $v) = $hit->()) {
    say "$k => $v";
}

my ($k, $v) = $hit->();  # restarts the iterator
say "$k --> $v";
($k, $v) = $hit->();     # next (keeps state)
say "$k --> $v";

sub get_each_it {
    my %h = @_;
    return sub { return each %h }
}
```

The repeated and continued iteration (after the hash is exhausted or for individual calls) is a basic property of the hash iterator that [each](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) uses, and in doing that

> So long as a given hash is unmodified you may rely on `keys`, `values` and `each` to repeatedly return the same order as each other.

Please study carefully how this works.

See [this article on Perl.com](https://www.perl.com/pub/2005/06/16/iterators.html/) about iterators, with a number of examples. A detailed discussion of iterators is given in [Iterator](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Iterator/Iterator.pm) module, along with a tutorial. I don't know the module well but docs are worth reading; each and every warning and caveat applies to `each`.

---

In case you don't need (or want) the capability to reset the iterator for continued iterations once the hash is exhausted, here is an alternative iterator from [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)'s comment using [splice](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html)

```
sub get_each_it {
    my @kv = @_;
    return sub { return splice @kv, 0, 2 }
}
```

This doesn't get entangled with `each` and it also iterates in the order of the submitted list.

Note that by properties of a [closure](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Persistent-Private-Variables) each code reference returned by the generator still retains its own iterator, which maintains its state when  invoked from various pieces of code. Use with care.

Also see an introductory note on [closure in perlfaq7](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What%27s-a-closure%3F)

Comment: is there a way to define a variable inline and then use it with each, perhaps using `do {}` or something similar?

Comment: @GorkemYurtseven I don't see how that would be possible, since it would run every time through, restarting the iterator.  See ikegami's answer for a complete explanation of what your code does, and for options.

Comment: @GorkemYurtseven I must ask, why? It isn't that the code needs this (to generate data for `while` dynamically), right?  You can just define the hash right there, or if you'd rather not have it floating around put it all in a sub. Perhaps return an iterator, what can turn out much nicer, too.

Comment: Alternative iterator: `sub get_each_it { my @a = @_; sub { splice @a, 0, 2 } }` Unlike `each`, it doesn't reset, but that shouldn't be a problem. I considered mentioning a custom iterator when I was writing my answer, but I ended up not including it because it doesn't help the OP at all; it still needs a loop-scoped variable.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you, added to my answer for when the resetting isn't needed or desired (and as it avoids `each`).  As for the purpose, the one reasonable aim I can see in the question is to iterate over key-value pairs from a dynamically generated list (without adding a variable at that scope).  Added this statement to the answer.  This is why I decided to add the iterator (where the variable is hidden in the sub). Also, since OP uses `each` I thought it useful to show that the hash iterator is resettable.

Comment: Re "*without adding a variable at that scope [...] This is why I decided to add the iterator*", But your iterator solution also adds a variable at that scope?? Thus my comment about not helping.

Comment: @ikegami Um, right, the iterator itself. (I didn't even notice it. I thought more of data.)  I am not sure what they want (perhaps just curious about doing it on the fly?) but I thought that this made sense to mention.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility to do what you apparently want to do, would be using a `for` loop. The (not so) anonymous hash goes in the initialisation expression. The test expression is the assignment of `each` and the iteration expression stays empty.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

for (my %h = (
              apple => 'red',
              orange => 'orange',
              grape => 'purple',
             );
     my ($key, $value) = each(%h);
    ) {
  print("$key: $value\n");
}
```

This can actually be seen as a sort of a `while` loop with an initialisation local to the loop. `%h` is only in scope in the loop. So it's not anonymous to the `for` loop and can be used with `each` but ceases to exist after the loop is done.

Comment: No reason to use a hash. Probably faster: `for (my @h = ( ... ); my ($key, $value) = splice(@h, 0, 2); ) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The while executes the expression on each loop, a ref to the hash works.

```
sub returnsHash {
    my %fruits = (
        apple  => "red",
        orange => "orange",
        grape  => "purple",
    );
    return \%fruits;
}
my $f = returnsHash() ;
while ( my ($key, $value) = each %{ $f } ) {
    print "$key => $value\n";
}
```

what is needed is a foreach:

```
use v5.36 ;
no warnings qw(experimental::for_list);
sub returnsHash {
    my %fruits = (
        apple  => "red",
        orange => "orange",
        grape  => "purple",
    );
    return %fruits;
}
foreach my ($key, $value) ( returnsHash() ) {
    print "$key => $value\n";
}
```